# Three.js TextGeometry - Z-rotated text looks italicized

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render some text onto a "fake 3D" backdrop (see my image link for a picture of what it looks like rendered), however when I rotate the text on the Z-axis to make the text look like it's a part of the fake 3D backdrop the text becomes distorted, almost looking italicized. I've tried rotation on the x and y axis as well to maybe change the depth perception but I can't get it to look right.

Anyone run into this or have thoughts?

Image:

[image: 3D image]

Code:

```
var desiredWidthInCSSPixels = 1100;
var desiredHeightInCSSPixels = 700;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var texture_loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var font_loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

renderer.setSize( desiredWidthInCSSPixels, desiredHeightInCSSPixels );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//this is the fake 3d backdrop "business cards"
texture_loader.load( "assets/images/mockups/mockup-1.png", function (texture) {
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 800, 600, 0 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    scene.add( cube );
});

//here's the company's logo
texture_loader.load( "assets/images/logo.svg", function (texture) {
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 60, 60, 0 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { transparent: true, map: texture } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [null, null, null, null, material, null] );

    cube.rotation.z = -150.12;

    cube.position.x = 60;
    cube.position.y = -40;


    scene.add( cube );
});

//the text loader that looks italicized
font_loader.load( 'assets/fonts/roboto_black_regular.json', function(font) {
    var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'My test text looks italic!!!', {
        font: font,
        size: 5,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 3,
        bevelSize: 8,
        bevelSegments: 5
    } );

    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xddd
    });

    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [material, null, null, null, null, null] );

    cube.position.x = 60;
    cube.position.y = -40;
    cube.position.z = 20;

    cube.rotation.x = .12;
    cube.rotation.z = -149.95;

    scene.add( cube );
});


camera.position.z = 200;

var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();


function xtest() {
    cube.rotation.x += .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.x);
}
function ytest() {
    cube.rotation.y += .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.y);
}
function ztest() {
    cube.rotation.z += .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.z);
}

function x1test() {
    cube.rotation.x -= .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.x);
}
function y1test() {
    cube.rotation.y -= .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.y);
}
function z1test() {
    cube.rotation.z -= .01;

    console.log(cube.rotation.z);
}
```

Comment: It looks like your orientation (either of the text, or your camera) is off. It might be worthwhile to try to figure out a good camera angle to mimic the camera angle of the original photo. That would make it much easier to manipulate the text, because it can remain aligned to a particular axis.

Comment: That looks like an orthographic image. Try using an orthographic camera and add to the scene only an instance of `THREE.AxisHelper`. Set `scene.background = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'image' );`. Rotate and pan the camera (but don't zoom) until the axes are as parallel as possible to the edges of the cards.